# 105 Shimano 10 speed shifters - compatibility with 11 speed rear derailleur

Tags: shimano, gears, compatibility, speed

I am building a bike and I am using 10 speed Shimano 105 shifters.
On the back I am using a 11 speed 105 rear derailluer (because is the only one I have at the moment).
The cassette I am using is a standard SHIMANO TIAGRA CS-HG500-10 10 SPEED CASSETTE 11-25T.

Unfortunately, I am having some problems: when in biggest cog or second one, the chain moves out of the tension pulley and gets stuck (by the way the chain is a 11 speed chain, so width should not be an issue).

Does it seem like there could be something wrong with the chain line?

Any of you knows why it happens?
Did it happen to you?

Thanks already for your input!

Comment: It happens because 11 and 10 speed shimano road components are incompatible, namely derailleurs and shifters.

Comment: Interestingly I use an 11 speed Campagnolo Athena rear mech with 10 speed Campagnolo Centaur shifters and it shifts absolutely fine, you really wouldn't know.

Comment: I think that Campagnolo might be the exception...
but I honestly did not know about the incompatibility in pull ratio between 10 and 11 road shimano shifters.
Thanks for clarifying it for me.

Comment: Yes, Campagnolo changed cable pull between 8- and 9-speed and has been the same since then. It's also not compatible with Shimano without adapters or cable routing kludges.

Comment: @PaoloGoatspeed SRAM also uses the same pull ratio on 10 and 11 speed road rear derailleurs, making them interchangeable. Shimano however is active heading in the opposite direction.

Comment: yes, Sram is at the moment the best option for mixed components, unfortunately much more pricey, probably because is so much ahead now.
I can say that anyway my combo 10 speed shifter + 9 speed rear mech has now worked very well for several months on shimano.

Answer (score 11):

This is to do with the different pull ratios employed by the different systems.
In your case 10 vs 11 speed Shimano.

http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

If you look at the table in the link - it says the 10 speed levers pull less than the 11 speed levers but the rear derailleur ratios are also vastly different.

Comment: I understand the difference in pull-ratio, and as soon as I tried it I realised it.
What I don't understand is why the chain, which is a 11 speed speed one, so perfect in width, on the 2 biggest cogs get off the pulley wheel.
is it because of the inclination of the chain?
I must say that I have put on a SLX triple crankset...so the angles of the chain are definitely all messed up.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing first-hand. I suspect it's alignment of the rear derailleur in those gears. If you can adjust the skipping out using the barrel adjuster - it will prove it is alignment.

Comment: looks like that the problem is the alignment of the chain...but ca't be sure...very weird, never seen a chain getting out like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an Ultegra 6701 10 speed shifter with and Ultegra 6800 RD on an Ultegra 10 speed cassette with an Ultegra 6701 triple crank with no issues. I am not a mechanic or an engineer to be certain, but it does appear that there is no cable ratio altering mechanism in the rear derailer that augments the amount of movement dictated by the shifter. Again, not a bike mechanic, perhaps I just got lucky.

Answer (score -5):

In my humble opinion it should work if you use a 10 speed chain instead of a 11spd chian.... The chain width is determined more by the cassette than the RD...The RD does only what the shifters tell it to do.....The spacing between the sprockets on a 11 spd cassette are narrower than those on a 10 speed cassette....Since you are using a 10 speed cassette....try using a 10 speed chain..... I am fairly confident that it should work......Good luck

Comment: No, it will not work. 11 speed Shimano systems use a different cable pull ratio, which means the 10 and 11 speed derailleurs move different amounts for the same length of cable pull. The derailleur will not index the chain correctly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've downvoted your answer because you're just stating your opinion (that the problem is the chain) and this opinion directly contradicts the existing answer, which is backed up by technical sources. In particular, the derailleur _doesn't_ just "do what the shifters tell it to do". The shifters move the cable a certain amount and the arm of the derailleur translates that into a certain amount of horizontal motion. The problem in this case is that the two are incompatible so the derailleur moves the wrong amount for each move of the cable.

Comment: You'd be right if the question was about 6/7/8 speed systems, where the inter-cog gap is the same, or any system with a plain non-indexed friction shifter.

Comment: yes, it would not work. Unfortunately shimano compatibility is much trickier than that.
Appreciated anyway the try and it is good to understand insights of how this all works